# Windows Form c# - Insert Each Line from RichTextBox to separate column of SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms-designer

I am a beginner in .NET Framework so, please guide me if my code has some errors.

I am creating a .NET application using C# in Windows Form of Visual Studio 2014 and using SQL Server 2014 for database.

I am trying to achieve a task where the customer enters text in a `RichTextBox` where the paragraph can also have multiple paragraphs. Each sentence ends with a full stop (.). What I am trying to achieve is the entered text should be saved to the database column where each line is separated ending at full stop and should be saved in a different column.

Here is what I have done so far in Visual Studio:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] values = richTextBox1.Text.Split('$');
        obj.url = "abc.com";
        foreach (string item in values)
        {
            obj.content_result= item;

        }
        dbobj.table_test.Add(obj);
        dbobj.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Content Added Successfully");
    }
```

---

My database table is as follows:

Table Name: Table_test

```
ID (int - Primary Key - Auto Increment) | Content varchar(MAX) | URL varchar(MAX)
```

---

This saves the data to database named `table_test` with columns named; content and url where the above code should insert data from `RichTextBox` to content where each sentence should be saved in a separate line.

E.g

If user enters the following text in `RichTextBox`:

He is a good boy. He does his work very well. He prefer to work early to avoid inconvenience.

The above string should be saved in database as:

```
ID | Content                                        | URL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | He is a good boy.                              | abc.com
 2 | He does his work very well                     | abc.com
 3 | He prefer to work early to avoid inconvenience | abc.com
```

But, the above data is saved in database as:

```
ID | Content     | URL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | He is a good boy. He does his work very well. He prefer to work early to avoid inconvenience. | abc.com
```

Please help me to fix this problem so each sentence is saved in different column of table.

Thanks :)

Comment: *The above string should be saved in database as: ...* no it should not ... even if you would fix splitting problem your code obviously will ended with `1 | He prefer to work early to avoid inconvenience | abc.com`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Table
{
    public int Id;
    public string Content;
    public string Url
}

string[] lines = richTextBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
List<Table> items = new List<Table>();
int id = 1;
for (int i=0;i < lines.Length; i++)
{
      string[] tmp = lines[i].Split('|');
      foreach (string x in tmp[1].Split('.'))
          if(!x.Trim()=="")
              items.Add(new Table{ Id = id++ , Content = x + ".", Url = tmp[2] }); 
}
```

Now you have all items in an array may use EF or just looping through its items to add them to your database.

Comment: Good answer Ashkan but as the op outlines, the text should be split by a full stop/period character .

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Thanks for the quick help but, the above code is giving a couple of strange errors like the list Table not declared and cannot convert from string to char in the first line. 

As i told, I am a complete newbie so can't figure out why these errors are appearing. 

Also, how the Entity framwork would be used to insert values to DB would also be appreciated. :)

Comment: @Ahmad Table was actually declared but was not in the code section (the start of the code) and there was an error in the Split that corrected. please see the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

you should split text with dot

```
string[] values = richTextBox1.Text.Split('.');
```

but if you have web site address in your text you should put a sign like ***$*** or something like that at the end of each sentence to split long text to array of strings